# Program not executable using Intel C++ compiller on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, dpc++

I wanna migrate from Linux to Windows. I use the Intel OneAPI C++ compiler. It works on Linux using VS Code or terminal. I haven't installed the Visual Studio app.
On Windows my code successfully compiles with g++ but using dpcpp I get the error:

```bash
Intel(R) oneAPI DPC++/C++ Compiler 2022.1.0 (2022.1.0.20220316)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm
dpcpp: warning: unable to find a Visual Studio installation; try running Clang from a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-cl.exe" -cc1 -triple spir64-unknown-unknown -aux-triple x86_64-pc-windows-msvc -fsycl-is-device -fdeclare-spirv-builtins -mllvm -sycl-opt -fenable-sycl-dae -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fdelayed-template-parsing -fms-compatibility-version=19.14 -Wno-sycl-strict "-fsycl-int-header=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-header-858320.h" "-fsycl-int-footer=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-footer-ecbeef.h" -sycl-std=2020 -fsycl-unnamed-lambda -fsycl-unique-prefix=d65f6f35f968e95c -Wspir-compat -emit-llvm-bc -emit-llvm-uselists -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name hello.cpp -mrelocation-model static -fveclib=SVML -mframe-pointer=all -menable-no-infs -menable-no-nans -menable-unsafe-fp-math -fno-signed-zeros -mreassociate -freciprocal-math -fdenormal-fp-math=preserve-sign,preserve-sign -ffp-contract=fast -fno-rounding-math -ffast-math -ffinite-math-only -fno-verbose-asm -mconstructor-aliases -aux-target-cpu x86-64 --dependent-lib=msvcrt --dependent-lib=libircmt --dependent-lib=svml_dispmd --dependent-lib=libdecimal --dependent-lib=libmmd --dependent-lib=oldnames -fdiagnostics-format msvc -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -ffunction-sections -resource-dir "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\lib\\clang\\14.0.0" -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\..\\include\\sycl" -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\..\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\..\\compiler\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\lib\\clang\\14.0.0\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../compiler/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\lib\\clang\\14.0.0\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../compiler/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -O2 -Wno-c++11-narrowing -std=c++17 -fdeprecated-macro "-fdebug-compilation-dir=D:\\Documents\\╨Я╤А╨╛╨╡╨║╤В╤Л\\c++ training" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length=120 -malign-double -fuse-line-directives -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -std=c++17 -fno-threadsafe-statics -fdelayed-template-parsing -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -mllvm -disable-hir-generate-mkl-call -mllvm -intel-libirc-allowed -mllvm -loopopt=0 -floopopt-pipeline=none -o "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-58f4dd.bc" -x c++ ".\\hello.cpp"
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 based upon LLVM 14.0.0git default target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm\..\compiler\include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\lib\clang\14.0.0\include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm\..\compiler\include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\lib\clang\14.0.0\include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm\..\include\sycl
 C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm\..\include
 C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm\..\compiler\include
 C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\lib\clang\14.0.0\include
End of search list.
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\llvm-link" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-58f4dd.bc" -o "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-2830d5.bc" --suppress-warnings
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-offload-bundler" -type=o -targets=sycl-spir64-unknown-unknown "-inputs=C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../lib\\libsycl-crt.obj" "-outputs=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-crt-a5bc2d.obj" -unbundle -allow-missing-bundles
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-offload-bundler" -type=o -targets=sycl-spir64-unknown-unknown "-inputs=C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../lib\\libsycl-complex.obj" "-outputs=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-complex-dbf11f.obj" -unbundle -allow-missing-bundles
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-offload-bundler" -type=o -targets=sycl-spir64-unknown-unknown "-inputs=C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../lib\\libsycl-complex-fp64.obj" "-outputs=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-complex-fp64-280fc3.obj" -unbundle -allow-missing-bundles
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-offload-bundler" -type=o -targets=sycl-spir64-unknown-unknown "-inputs=C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../lib\\libsycl-cmath.obj" "-outputs=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-cmath-95e8ea.obj" -unbundle -allow-missing-bundles
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-offload-bundler" -type=o -targets=sycl-spir64-unknown-unknown "-inputs=C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../lib\\libsycl-cmath-fp64.obj" "-outputs=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-cmath-fp64-a7282d.obj" -unbundle -allow-missing-bundles
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-offload-bundler" -type=o -targets=sycl-spir64-unknown-unknown "-inputs=C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../lib\\libsycl-fallback-cassert.obj" "-outputs=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-fallback-cassert-07b114.obj" -unbundle -allow-missing-bundles
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-offload-bundler" -type=o -targets=sycl-spir64-unknown-unknown "-inputs=C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../lib\\libsycl-fallback-cstring.obj" "-outputs=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-fallback-cstring-4ffbd6.obj" -unbundle -allow-missing-bundles
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-offload-bundler" -type=o -targets=sycl-spir64-unknown-unknown "-inputs=C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../lib\\libsycl-fallback-complex.obj" "-outputs=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-fallback-complex-e71c2d.obj" -unbundle -allow-missing-bundles
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-offload-bundler" -type=o -targets=sycl-spir64-unknown-unknown "-inputs=C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../lib\\libsycl-fallback-complex-fp64.obj" "-outputs=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-fallback-complex-fp64-fb1ae0.obj" -unbundle -allow-missing-bundles
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-offload-bundler" -type=o -targets=sycl-spir64-unknown-unknown "-inputs=C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../lib\\libsycl-fallback-cmath.obj" "-outputs=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-fallback-cmath-3b1e3d.obj" -unbundle -allow-missing-bundles
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-offload-bundler" -type=o -targets=sycl-spir64-unknown-unknown "-inputs=C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../lib\\libsycl-fallback-cmath-fp64.obj" "-outputs=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-fallback-cmath-fp64-d68d1c.obj" -unbundle -allow-missing-bundles
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\llvm-link" -only-needed "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-2830d5.bc" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-crt-a5bc2d.obj" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-complex-dbf11f.obj" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-complex-fp64-280fc3.obj" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-cmath-95e8ea.obj" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-cmath-fp64-a7282d.obj" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-fallback-cassert-07b114.obj" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-fallback-cstring-4ffbd6.obj" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-fallback-complex-e71c2d.obj" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-fallback-complex-fp64-fb1ae0.obj" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-fallback-cmath-3b1e3d.obj" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libsycl-fallback-cmath-fp64-d68d1c.obj" -o "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-b3cdd5.bc" --suppress-warnings
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin\\sycl-post-link" -split=auto -emit-param-info -symbols -emit-exported-symbols -split-esimd -lower-esimd -O2 -spec-const=rt -o "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-d7c5bc.table" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-b3cdd5.bc"
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\file-table-tform" -extract=Code -drop_titles -o "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-9d7a68.txt" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-d7c5bc.table"
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\llvm-foreach" "--in-file-list=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-9d7a68.txt" "--in-replace=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-9d7a68.txt" --out-ext=spv "--out-file-list=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-827aef.txt" "--out-replace=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-827aef.txt" -- "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\llvm-spirv" -o "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-827aef.txt" -spirv-max-version=1.3 -spirv-debug-info-version=ocl-100 -spirv-allow-extra-diexpressions -spirv-allow-unknown-intrinsics=llvm.genx. -spirv-ext=-all,+SPV_EXT_shader_atomic_float_add,+SPV_EXT_shader_atomic_float_min_max,+SPV_KHR_no_integer_wrap_decoration,+SPV_KHR_float_controls,+SPV_KHR_expect_assume,+SPV_INTEL_subgroups,+SPV_INTEL_media_block_io,+SPV_INTEL_device_side_avc_motion_estimation,+SPV_INTEL_fpga_loop_controls,+SPV_INTEL_fpga_memory_attributes,+SPV_INTEL_fpga_memory_accesses,+SPV_INTEL_unstructured_loop_controls,+SPV_INTEL_fpga_reg,+SPV_INTEL_blocking_pipes,+SPV_INTEL_function_pointers,+SPV_INTEL_kernel_attributes,+SPV_INTEL_io_pipes,+SPV_INTEL_inline_assembly,+SPV_INTEL_arbitrary_precision_integers,+SPV_INTEL_float_controls2,+SPV_INTEL_vector_compute,+SPV_INTEL_fast_composite,+SPV_INTEL_fpga_buffer_location,+SPV_INTEL_joint_matrix,+SPV_INTEL_arbitrary_precision_fixed_point,+SPV_INTEL_arbitrary_precision_floating_point,+SPV_INTEL_arbitrary_precision_floating_point,+SPV_INTEL_variable_length_array,+SPV_INTEL_fp_fast_math_mode,+SPV_INTEL_fpga_cluster_attributes,+SPV_INTEL_loop_fuse,+SPV_INTEL_long_constant_composite,+SPV_INTEL_fpga_invocation_pipelining_attributes,+SPV_INTEL_fpga_dsp_control,+SPV_INTEL_arithmetic_fence,+SPV_INTEL_runtime_aligned,+SPV_INTEL_task_sequence,+SPV_INTEL_optnone,+SPV_INTEL_token_type,+SPV_INTEL_bfloat16_conversion,+SPV_INTEL_joint_matrix,+SPV_INTEL_hw_thread_queries,+SPV_INTEL_memory_access_aliasing "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-9d7a68.txt"
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\file-table-tform" -replace=Code,Code -o "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-65c029.table" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-d7c5bc.table" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-827aef.txt"
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-offload-wrapper" "-o=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\wrapper-3cdeea.bc" -host=x86_64-pc-windows-msvc -target=spir64 -kind=sycl -batch "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-65c029.table"
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\llc" -filetype=obj -o "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-002a07.obj" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\wrapper-3cdeea.bc"
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\append-file" ".\\hello.cpp" "--append=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-footer-ecbeef.h" --orig-filename=./hello.cpp "--output=C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-8ede2b.cpp" --use-include
 "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\clang-cl.exe" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.14.0 -sycl-std=2020 -fsycl-unnamed-lambda -fsycl-unique-prefix=d65f6f35f968e95c -include "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-header-858320.h" -dependency-filter "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-header-858320.h" -fsycl-enable-int-header-diags -fsycl-is-host -emit-obj -mincremental-linker-compatible --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name hello.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -fveclib=SVML -mframe-pointer=none -menable-no-infs -menable-no-nans -menable-unsafe-fp-math -fno-signed-zeros -mreassociate -freciprocal-math -fdenormal-fp-math=preserve-sign,preserve-sign -ffp-contract=fast -fno-rounding-math -ffast-math -ffinite-math-only -fno-verbose-asm -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -mllvm -x86-enable-unaligned-vector-move=true -tune-cpu generic -D_MT -D_DLL --dependent-lib=msvcrt --dependent-lib=libircmt --dependent-lib=svml_dispmd --dependent-lib=libdecimal --dependent-lib=libmmd --dependent-lib=oldnames --dependent-lib=sycl -fdiagnostics-format msvc -v -ffunction-sections "-fcoverage-compilation-dir=D:\\Documents\\╨Я╤А╨╛╨╡╨║╤В╤Л\\c++ training" -resource-dir "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\lib\\clang\\14.0.0" -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\..\\include\\sycl" -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\..\\include" -iquote . -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm\\..\\compiler\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\lib\\clang\\14.0.0\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../compiler/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\lib\\clang\\14.0.0\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\bin-llvm/../compiler/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -header-base-path "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows" -O2 -Wno-c++11-narrowing -std=c++17 -fdeprecated-macro "-fdebug-compilation-dir=D:\\Documents\\╨Я╤А╨╛╨╡╨║╤В╤Л\\c++ training" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length=120 -malign-double -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fuse-line-directives -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fms-compatibility-version=19.14 -std=c++17 -fdelayed-template-parsing -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -fintel-compatibility -mllvm -disable-hir-generate-mkl-call -mllvm -intel-libirc-allowed -mllvm -loopopt=0 -floopopt-pipeline=none -mllvm -enable-lv -o "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-06b369.obj" -x c++ "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-8ede2b.cpp"
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 based upon LLVM 14.0.0git default target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm\..\compiler\include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\lib\clang\14.0.0\include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm\..\compiler\include"
#include "..." search starts here:
 .
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm\..\include\sycl
 C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm\..\include
 C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm\..\compiler\include
 C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\lib\clang\14.0.0\include
End of search list.
 "link.exe" -out:hello.exe /IGNORE:4078 "-libpath:lib\\amd64" "-libpath:atlmfc\\lib\\amd64" "-libpath:C:\\PROGRA~2\\Intel\\oneAPI\\compiler\\20221~1.0\\windows\\lib\\clang\\14.0.0\\lib\\windows" -nologo "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-06b369.obj" "C:\\Users\\wusik\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\hello-002a07.obj"
dpcpp: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
dpcpp: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Includes don't work at all:

```bash
.....
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 .
 C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm\..\include\sycl
 C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm\..\include
 C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\bin-llvm\..\compiler\include
 C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\20221~1.0\windows\lib\clang\14.0.0\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\tbb\latest\env\..\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\dev-utilities\latest\include
End of search list.
.\hello.cpp(3,10): fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I also tried to use VS Code extensions instead of the terminal in accordance with [this](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-intel-oneapi-hpc-linux/top/run-a-sample-project-with-vscode.html) manual, but at the Cmake step, I get an error about it doesn't be supported in Windows target.

How to fix the problem? Can I use the compiler without installing the Visual Studio?

Comment: Looks to me like you are supposed to install Visual Studio as well.

Comment: @user17732522 Can I use dpcpp without Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't know. If that is what you want to do, I would recommend adding it to the question.

Comment: `dpcpp: warning: unable to find a Visual Studio installation; try running Clang from a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]` - Seems like it requires VS, so install VS. It's a dependency just like `build-essential` is on Linux. The community edition is usually the right one, make sure you select "Desktop development with C++" and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need Visual Studio installed if you plan on using dpc++, as it's indicated as a prerequisite in [the compiler docs](https://intel.github.io/llvm-docs/GetStartedGuide.html).